# make an android application compatible with all Android sizes and types

Tags: android, version

is There any possibility to make an android application compatible with  all Android sizes and categories, for Example an application compatible with SamSung S3 and SamSung Tab 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this :http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can support different devices, if you pay the price. There are some approaches to do this, such as support libraries and creating device/property oriented layouts.

Have a look at this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html An example of layout supporting:

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml
```